# Need to Find minimum value of a column that is greater than a certain value

Tags: sql

I have a table named Event,

[image]

I need to find the minimum Value of an Entity that is greater than the maximum Value when the Status is 5. If no Value is greater, then return the maximum Value when Status is 5.

For ex, the output of this table should be,

[image]

Can we achieve this using query? What is the best possible way to get this output?

Comment: Which is the name of your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this should work on the most of the RDBS:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN Status <> 5 THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity) AS not5statusMax
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 5 THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity) AS 5statusMax
    FROM Event
) DS
    WHERE (statusMax IS NULL AND Value = not5statusMax)
        OR (Value = statusMax)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the max window function then aggregate as the following:

```
select Entity, min(Value) Value
from
(
  select *,
    max(case when Status = 5 then Value end) over (partition by Entity) status_five_value,
    max(Value) over (partition by Entity) mx
  from tbl
) T
where value > status_five_value -- when the values are greater than the (value where status = 5) 
      or
      (status_five_value = mx and Status = 5) -- when there are no values greater than the (value where status = 5) 
group by Entity
order by Entity
```

The logic here is, for each entity find the minimum value from the values that are greater than `status_five_value`, if no rows are returned by this condition for an entity, then the `status_five_value` is equal to the `max(Value)` for the entire entity, for this case, return only the row with `Status = 5`.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dDxkzEuE)

Comment: @sakthivel, maybe you have to edit your posted expected output , the accepted answer is giving different output than you specified in your question. https://dbfiddle.uk/bT0Tl-q6